# Bootstrap-rails, how to change body size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Now, the title may make sound like the laziest question but bear with me.

The approximate structure of my site is of the format:

```
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The view is styled by bootstrap, and the overriding css is placed in

```
app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
```

Now, I have tried changing the **height** and **min-height** of the body and container like this;

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

etc, but the outcome is unexpected.

If I increase the height of `container` to exceed the height of `body`, it simply overflows the boundaries of `body`, instead of `body` growing accordingly to match it. In a similar manner, if I **decrease** the height of `body` to fall below the height of `container`, the `container` will not shrink to match `body`.

I am not very proficient in CSS so I might be overlooking something very fundamental here, so any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or,

```
body {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, both the navbar (the links on the top of the page) and the container (the main content of the page) are both (and should be, in my opinion) wrapped inside the body, next to each other. I found out the problem though - deep inside the `navbar`-element there was another `container` element which obviously scaled alongside the other container.